# JQuery UI Autocomplete prevent backspace from searching

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When a user hits the backspace key the search is triggered. How can I prevent this from happening? I have tried the following code, but it appears to only work after the second time the backspace key is pressed.

```
var $cached_input = $("#myinput");

$cached_input.autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 700,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete("widget")
         .find("ui-menu-item-alternate")
          .removeClass("ui-menu-item-alternate")
         .end()
         .find("li.ui-menu-item:odd a")
          .addClass("ui-menu-item-alternate");
    },
    source: function (request, response) {
        var params = { searchTerm: request.term }

        //ajax call made here to load the data...
    },
    minLength: minChars
}).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
        $cached_input.autocomplete("disable");
    } else {
        $cached_input.autocomplete("enable");
    }
});
```

**Edit**
As a workaround I have implemented the following changes (comments next to each) and it seems to do the job. Still open to better solutions if they exist.

```
var $cached_input = $("#myinput");
var performSearch = true; //added variable to determine if I should search

$cached_input.autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 700,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete("widget")
         .find("ui-menu-item-alternate")
          .removeClass("ui-menu-item-alternate")
         .end()
         .find("li.ui-menu-item:odd a")
          .addClass("ui-menu-item-alternate");
    },
    source: function (request, response) {
        if (performSearch) { //check variable before performing search
            var params = { searchTerm: request.term }

            //ajax call made here to load the data...
        }
    },
    minLength: minChars
}).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
        performSearch = false; //do not perform the search
    } else {
        performSearch = true; //perform the search
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a submit on select option that may be detecting backspace as a selection?

Comment: I did not see that happening when i binned the logic that you provided in the question . Here take a look at it yourself : http://jsbin.com/oceguTI/1/edit

Are you sure you have added all the relevant codes here in the question ?

Comment: @mr-jack I am not sure I follow your question. There is a select event but that is triggered when an item is selected from the menu at which point it is too late.

Comment: @the-dark-knight It does not happen in the demo you provided since I removed the ajax call that loads the data in the source property. I did not provide that code as I do not believe it is related to the issue at hand since by the time that code is executed it is too late.

Comment: The autocomplete seems to be an addon. Does it autosubmit the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I have implemented the following changes (comments next to each) and it seems to do the job. Still open to better solutions if they exist.

```
var $cached_input = $("#myinput"); var performSearch = true; //added variable to determine if I should search

$cached_input.autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 700,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete("widget")
         .find("ui-menu-item-alternate")
          .removeClass("ui-menu-item-alternate")
         .end()
         .find("li.ui-menu-item:odd a")
          .addClass("ui-menu-item-alternate");
    },
    source: function (request, response) {
        if (performSearch) { //check variable before performing search
            var params = { searchTerm: request.term }

            //ajax call made here to load the data...
        }
    },
    minLength: minChars }).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
        performSearch = false; //do not perform the search
    } else {
        performSearch = true; //perform the search
    } });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$cached_input.autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 700,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete("widget")
         .find("ui-menu-item-alternate")
          .removeClass("ui-menu-item-alternate")
         .end()
         .find("li.ui-menu-item:odd a")
          .addClass("ui-menu-item-alternate");
    },
    source: function (request, response) {
        var params = { searchTerm: request.term }

        //ajax call made here to load the data...
    },
    minLength: minChars
}).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $cached_input.autocomplete("enable");
                $cached_input.autocomplete("search", $cached_input.val());
            }
            else if ((e.keyCode == 8) || (this.value == "") || (e.keyCode == 46)) 
            {
                $cached_input.autocomplete("disable");
            }
```

Comment: This still performs a search when the backspace key is pressed. In addition, the search is not initially performed until the enter key is pressed which I do not want.

Comment: then remove the e.keyCode === 13 condition part and use keyCode == 8 part only

Comment: That would leave me with what I already tried which is if keycode == 8 call disable correct?

Comment: instead of keypress try  .keyup(function(e)
           {
               if(e.keyCode == 8) 
               $( "#tags" ).autocomplete( "disable" )
               else
               $( "#tags" ).autocomplete( "enable" )
           });

Comment: Same behavior as before. The first time the search is performed and all subsequent times it is not. I have edited my question with what I found to be a possible solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
$(document).on('keyup cut paste change keydown', 'input[data-input_type="autocomplete"]', function (e) {
 $(this).autocomplete({
        source: mySource();
}
```

This way you can control the events that will trigger the autocomplete in this case: keyup, cut, paste, and keydown. Where data-input_type = "autocomplete" is an personal tag to the input just to say it belongs to the autocomplete group of DOM elements, but you can call it by a class or however you want. Hope this helps someone.